# How to get exact opposite of a coordinate in itextsharp? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

Here is my code:

```
        Dim ImagePath = "C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\Logo.jpg"
        Dim Img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ImagePath)
        Img.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.PageSize.Width - 36.0F - 100.0F,
  doc.PageSize.Height - 36.0F - 99.0F)
        wri.DirectContent.AddImage(Img)
```

I want to put another image directly at the opposite side (this one is on the right side, I want another photo on the left) of it. But I can't seem to display it right. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following code to add an image to the right:

```
Img.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.PageSize.Width - 36.0F - 100.0F, doc.PageSize.Height - 36.0F - 99.0F)
```

Now change the X value to put an image to the left:

```
Img.SetAbsolutePosition(36.0F, doc.PageSize.Height - 36.0F - 99.0F)
```